# Efficient matching of two arrays (how to use KDTree)

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, kdtree

I have two 2d arrays, `obs1` and `obs2`. They represent two independent measurement series, and both have *dim0 = 2*, and slightly different *dim1*, say `obs1.shape = (2, 250000)`, and `obs2.shape = (2, 250050)`. `obs1[0]` and `obs2[0]` signify time, and `obs1[1]` and `obs2[1]` signify some spatial coordinate. Both arrays are (more or less) sorted by time. The times and coordinates *should* be identical between the two measurement series, but in reality they aren't. Also, not each measurement from `obs1` has a corresponding value in `obs2` and vice-versa. Another problem is that there might be a slight offset in the times.

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to associate the best matching value from `obs2` to each measurement in `obs1`. Currently, I do it like this:

```
define dt = some_maximum_time_difference
define dx = 3
j = 0
i = 0
matchresults = np.empty(obs1.shape[1])
for j in obs1.shape[1]:
    while obs1[0, j] - obs2[0, j] < dt:
        i += 1
    matchresults[j] = i - dx + argmin(abs(obs1[1, i] - obs2[1, i-dx:i+dx+1]))
```

This yields good results. However, it is extremely slow, running in a loop.

I would be very thankful for ideas on how to improve this algorithm speed-wise, e.g. using KDtree or something similar.

Comment: Can you please expand a bit on `first_obs2_index_with_time_difference_lessthan_delta_t
    resulting_i = i + argmin(abs(obs1[1, i] - obs2[1, i-delta_x:i+delta_x+1])`? Assuming that you are not performing another loop here, I don't believe KDTrees would speed things up too much.

Comment: @MikyDinescu thanks for your question; I updated the algorithm in the original post.

Comment: can you post a bit of data, and your expected results?

Comment: I was wondering of anybody replied to you. Thanks for posting more details but unfortunately it's still unclear to me how your current algo. works.. I'm not a python developer so maybe somebody else will chime in. I would suggest though to present your algorithm in pseudo code instead. Or maybe ask on a more CS stack exchange..

Comment: @andreas-h did you check the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Using `cKDTree` for this case would look like:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

obs2 = array with shape (2, m)
obs1 = array with shape (2, n)

kdt = cKDTree(obs2.T)
dist, indices = kdt.query(obs1.T)
```

where `indices` will contain the column indices in `obs2` corresponding to each observation in `obs1`. Note that I had to transpose `obs1` and `obs2`.