# Ising Model: How to shorten simulation time?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am simulating the [Ising Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) of ferromagnets in dimensions higher than 3 using a simple coding structure but am having some problems with efficiency. In my code, there is one particular function that is the bottleneck.

In the simulation process, it is necessary to find what are called the nearest neighbors of a given site. For example, in the 2D Ising model, spins occupy the lattice at every point, noted by two numbers: (x,y). The nearest neighbors of the point at (x,y) are the four adjacent values, namely (x+1,y),(x-1,y),(x,y+1),(x,y-1). In 5D, the spin at some lattice site has coordinates (a,b,c,d,e) with 10 nearest neighbors, in the same form as before but for each point in the tuple.

Now here's the code that is given the following inputs:

```
"site_i is a random value between 0 and n-1 denoting the site of the ith spin"
"coord is an array of size (n**dim,dim) that contains the coordinates of ever spin"
"spins is an array of shape (n**dim,1) that contains the spin values (-1 or 1)"
"n is the lattice size and dim is the dimensionality"
"neighbor_coupling is the number that tells the function to return the neighbor spins that are one spacing away, two spacing away, etc."

def calc_neighbors(site_i,coord,spins,n,dim,neighbor_coupling):
    # Extract all nearest neighbors
    # Obtain the coordinates of each nearest neighbor
    # How many neighbors to extract
    num_NN = 2*dim
    # Store the results in a result array 
    result_coord = np.zeros((num_NN,dim))
    result_spins = np.zeros((num_NN,1))
    # Get the coordinates of the ith site
    site_coord = coord[site_i]
    # Run through the + and - for each scalar value in the vector in site_coord
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,dim):
        assert count <= num_NN, "Accessing more than nearest neighbors values."
        site_coord_i = site_coord[i]
        plus = site_coord_i + neighbor_coupling
        minus = site_coord_i - neighbor_coupling

        # Implement periodic boundaries
        if (plus > (n-1)): plus = plus - n
        if (minus < 0): minus = n - np.abs(minus)

        # Store the coordinates
        result_coord[count] = site_coord
        result_coord[count][i] = minus
        # Store the spin value
        spin_index = np.where(np.all(result_coord[count]==coord,axis=1))[0][0]
        result_spins[count] = spins[spin_index]
        count = count + 1

        # Store the coordinates
        result_coord[count] = site_coord
        result_coord[count][i] = plus
        # Store the spin value
        spin_index = np.where(np.all(result_coord[count]==coord,axis=1))[0][0]
        result_spins[count] = spins[spin_index]
        count = count + 1
```

I don't really know how I can make this faster but it would help a lot. Perhaps a different way of storing everything?

Comment: check if you could use SciPy's [cKDTree](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26425437/832621) in your case, it is very efficient for finding closest neighbours

Comment: So your lattice is square? In that case it would be much better to store the spins in an N-dimensional array.

Comment: I didn't realize numpy had an ndarray type. Wow, that would have made things much much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just some suggestions for straightening: there is a lot of copying while you attempt to document every step of the calculation. Without sacrificing this, you could drop `site_coord_i`, and then

```
    # New coords, implement periodic boundaries
    plus = (site_coord[i] + neighbor_coupling) % n
    minus = (site_coord[i] - neighbor_coupling + n) % n
```

This avoids intermediate steps ("if...").
One other suggestions would be to defer using a subarray until you really need it:

```
    # Store the coordinates
    rcc = site_coord
    rcc[i] = plus
    # Store the spin value
    spin_index = np.where(np.all(rcc==coord,axis=1))[0][0]
    result_spins[count] = spins[spin_index]
    result_coord[count] = rcc
    count += 1
```

The goal is to reduce the number of dimensions of the variable used in the comparison, and to prefer local variables.